# IOS topper disappeared when model multiple Viewcontroller with one UINavigationController

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiviewcontroller

1. top bar disappeared

When I implement this:

```
process[UINavigationController --model->> UIViewController --model-->> UIViewController]
```

...why does the **UINavigationItem topBar** of the second **UIViewController** disappear?

Any ideas?

Comment: Please explain in details and show image for better description.

Comment: [A viewcontroller ---modal segue----> navigationcontroller-----> B viewcontroller ----modal segue---> C viewcontroller]   when i implement this,the topper of B view controller is here, but when i arrive C view controller  topper disappeared. any idea?